# Computer screen flashes then crashes

Tags: display, bsod, crash, reboot

This problem had been occuring for like 2 weeks. What happens is that sometimes when im using the computer the screen will start flashing for 10-20 sec then the computer will restart automatically, The flashing screen have different colors most of the time. Sometimes i can have the computer on for the entire day without anything happening and other times it can happen right after i have started it, i have never seen it occur on the startup screen.

I have a recording and a photo of it happening you can see it here: https://vimeo.com/828403137
https://i.stack.imgur.com/krcTX.jpg

My specs are

```
Host Name:                 DESKTOP3
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          User
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                00325-81235-90208-AAOEM
Original Install Date:     2021-03-13, 14:27:33
System Boot Time:          2023-05-19, 19:12:00
System Manufacturer:       LENOVO
System Model:              90JL00D4MW
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2808 Mhz
BIOS Version:              LENOVO O3LKT20A, 2019-03-07
Windows Directory:         C:\WINDOWS
System Directory:          C:\WINDOWS\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume3
System Locale:             sv;Svenska
Input Locale:              sv;Svenska
Time Zone:                 (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien
Total Physical Memory:     16 258 MB
Available Physical Memory: 11 173 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  20 610 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 13 159 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    7 451 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    WORKGROUP
```

I have an:

Intel(R) Core(TM) I5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz  2.81 GHz
16GB RAM
64 bit
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

My display is: 2560 x 1440 (32 bit) (59Hz)
I have a razer mouse and keybord and a HP monitor

Additional notes
I use Wallpaper Engine, i dont know if that has something to do with the problem but i wouldnt be surprised if it did

Sometimes after the computer has crashed and restarted the lights in my keyboard have turned off.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: You may have a hardware problem:  Get the manufacturer's Hardware Test App and test all hardware.  If hardware is fine, you might try a Windows 10 Repair Install that will also update all drivers.

Comment: @John Sorry for a late response but do you know where I can find the manufacturers hardware app? (Im really bad with computers)

Comment: Find the support site for each major part and see if the site offers a test app.